# Firebase current user not keeping state in NextJS

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication

I am making a app using firebase and nextjs and i have created a login page when i login and try to get the current user i get undefined. This issue start with me a few days ago in in react native too first it was keeping state and after the firebase update form 9.2.0 to 10.0.0 the user is not keeping state.

Nextjs Code:

AuthConext.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { onAuthStateChanged, getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import firebase_app from "@/firebase/config";

const auth = getAuth(firebase_app);

export const AuthContext = React.createContext({});

export const useAuthContext = () => React.useContext(AuthContext);

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        console.log("user change");
        setUser(user);
      } else {
        setUser(null);
      }
      setLoading(false);
    });

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user }}>
      {loading ? <div>Loading...</div> : children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Login.js (Check comments) :

```
 const { user } = useAuthContext();   // Gives Current User
  
  async function handleSignIn() {
    if (password && email) {
      const { result, error } = await signIn(email, password); // signin with email function rest is   handled in an other file where the signin with Email Passowrd fucntion is called
      
      console.log(user);    // Giving undefined
      if (error) {
        setErrorStop(error);
      } else {
        router.push("/blog");  // Tried on /blog page too the same AuthContext but still un defined
      }
    }
  }
```

Some might say that the user might taking time to initilize i tried it on a seperate page but it was still giving undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're expecting the `user` to be updated immediately after `signIn` function is complete:

```
const { result, error } = await signIn(email, password);      
console.log(user);
```

That's not the way Firebase auth state listeners work, nor is it the way that react hooks work.  `user` will not get updated during a component's code.  The current run of the component must fully complete, and then a new run will happen with the updated user variable.  Your component should have a check for user separately from the sign in process.

Comment: Yes this was correct somewhat but the real problem was with my _app.js, i wrote the AuthConextprovied in the layout.js rather then in app.js. Thanks